# Alignment Issue With display:table-cell in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-tables

I'm having a cross-browser positioning issue with Firefox. I'm using display:table and display:table-cell. Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cSq6W/1/

Basically, if you open this up in Safari, Chrome or IE the `<li>`s are all centered (which is what I want). When you open it in Firefox, everything is justified to the left.

I've tried numerous solutions to realign everything but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried `position:absolute` with `left:0` to start from a common starting point but even then the Firefox `<li>`s were not aligned with the other browsers.

The reason I'm using display:table-cell is because it seems to be easier to control across all browser (particularly IE) and has worked on other pages on the site. Any ideas on why it would be misaligned in Firefox (btw this issue persists from FF5 to FF10)?

Comment: Can you just post the code in question, at jsfiddle?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't really have an idea of what it is that's causing the problem so that's why I posted the whole code. I didn't know if it was a CSS issue from a parent div that was causing it or something. It's basically just the <ul>s that I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to define display:inline-block to your `img` & define `text-align:center` to it's parent.
Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cSq6W/2/

**UPDATED**

For IE7 there a hack check the link
http://jsfiddle.net/cSq6W/5/

Comment: Now, it's misaligned in IE7 (basically the left column is where the right column is and the right column is below). I'll post as a new question unless you know of any quick fixes (it works fine in IE8 and IE9, just not in IE7)...

Comment: The hack is on the '#navbar a' div. The problem is with the .resources_table_cell div though. I've tried placing the hack in a couple different places but it didn't seem to change the problem. Am I possibly placing it in the wrong place?

Comment: it's hack for inline-block not for display:table-cell because display:table-cell is not working in IE7

Comment: I've got another page on the site that I've set up the same way (with display:table-cell) so I'm confused as to what's causing the conflict...I'll keep looking and see if I find anything.